# Find maximum of a composition of floor functions

Tags: maxima-minima, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is there a way to find the maximum of a composition of floor functions?

$f(x) = \lfloor \lfloor x \times a \rfloor \times b \rfloor \times c \rfloor \times d - x$

$x \in [n, m], n \geq 0, n < m$

$a, b, c, d > 0$

I need $x$ so $f(x)$ is the highest or at least a smaller interval [n', m'] so I can iterate to find it.

Comment: What's represents $floor(x×a,p1)$?

Comment: I just updated the question and added details about $floor$.

Comment: @Dromit It might be easier to read if you use the LaTeX typesetting for floor: $\lfloor x \rfloor$. This is typed as "\lfloor x \rfloor".

Comment: You could also express $\operatorname{floor}(x,p)$ as $\frac{\lfloor 10^p x \rfloor}{10^p}$.

Comment: I simplified it quite a bit, check it now please.

Answer (score 0):

A heuristic solution could be to bound each floor function above and below:
$$\begin{aligned}
a(x-1)&\leq\lfloor ax\rfloor\leq ax\\
b(a(x-1)-1)&\leq\lfloor b \lfloor ax\rfloor \rfloor\leq abx\\
(abcd-1)x-(cd+bcd+abcd)&\leq d\lfloor c\lfloor b \lfloor ax\rfloor \rfloor\rfloor -x\leq (abcd-1)x\\
\end{aligned}$$

Hence, the maximum of $f(x)=d\lfloor c\lfloor b \lfloor ax\rfloor \rfloor\rfloor -x$ over the interval $[n,m]$ lies in the interval:

$$[(abcd-1)m-(cd+bcd+abcd), (abcd-1)m]$$

[image]

Figure: $f(x)$ in black, the bounds of $f(x)$ in blue, $x=n,m$ in red and the bounds of the maximum in green.  The tricky part is that the maximum of $f(x)$ isn't necessarily on the piece of the curve that touches $x=m$, as shown in the figure.

Graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/l9tiacrofk.

Comment: Not sure how to use this to find $x_{max}$.

Comment: @Dromit Look at the triangle formed by the red line at $x=m$, the blue upper bound of $f(x)$ and the green lower bound of the maximum of $f(x)$. If your maximal $f(x)$ is in the height of that triangle, then your $x_{\mathrm{max}}$ is in the base of that triangle.

Comment: Find the intersection of the relevant lines and you can get the base of the triangle. It works better when the constants are larger and when $m>>n$. https://i.imgur.com/EhquAhs.png